# Creating Array with specific Key Value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, return-value, var-dump

In order to have an array output like

```
array(2) { ["2012-08-16"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(24) "RLI Class #42 Graduation" ["event_date"]=> string(10) "2012-08-16" } } ["2012-08-24"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(10) "Test Event" ["event_date"]=> string(10) "2012-08-24" } } }
```

I am trying the following

```
$array = array('title' => $mytitle, 'event_date' => $myyear."-".$mymonth."-".$myday);
$events[$array['event_date']] = $array['title'];
```

However the output I get is

```
array(1) { [""]=> NULL } array(1) { ["2012-8-24"]=> string(10) "Test Event" } array(1) { ["2012-8-16"]=> string(25) "RLI Class #42 Graduation" }
```

How should I change the code to let $events output in the desired array format?

***EDIT***
Just in case a little background of the code will be helpful to find the solution, here it is

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
$mytime = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-start-date', true); // this has 2 entries: 1>1347408000 and 2>1347408000
$mydate = date("Y-m-D",$mytime);
$mydatearr = getdate($mytime);
$myday = $mydatearr['mday'];  // returns values 16 and 24
$mymonth = $mydatearr['mon']; // returns values 8 and 8
$myyear = $mydatearr['year']; // returns values 2012 and 2012
$mytitle = $post->post_title;
if (($myyear == $year) &&  ($mymonth == $month)) //The $year is declared earlier as 2012 and $month as  8
```

Next was my code which I replaced with

```
 $events = array(); ## Declare the new array.
     foreach ($array as $line) {
   $event_date = $line['event_date']; ## Set event_date to a variable
   $events[$event_date] = array( 'title' => $line['title'], 'event_date' => $event_date );  ###add new value to new array with key value            }
 var_dump($events);
```

And the endwhile

```
   endwhile;
```

**EDIT**
OK. I seem to have mistakenly deleted my $array declaration and earlier declared the $events array inside the loop. So I am updating the new code

```
$events = array(); ## Declare the new array.
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
$mytime = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-start-date', true);
$mydate = date("Y-m-D",$mytime);
$mydatearr = getdate($mytime);
$myday = $mydatearr['mday'];
$mymonth = $mydatearr['mon'];
$myyear = $mydatearr['year'];
$mytitle = $post->post_title;
if (($myyear == $year) &&  ($mymonth == $month))
$array = array('title' => $mytitle, 'event_date' => $myyear."-".$mymonth."-".$myday);
foreach ($array as $line) {
$event_date = $line['event_date']; ## Set event_date to a variable
$events[$event_date] = array( 'title' => $line['title'], 'event_date' => $event_date );  ###add new value to new array with key value
}
var_dump($events);
endwhile;
```

The var_dump for $array gives

```
NULL
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/newmedia/public_html/dev/wp-gallerific/wp-content/themes/lajcc-theme/calendar.php on line 165
array(2) { ["title"]=> string(10) "Test Event" ["event_date"]=> string(9) "2012-8-24" } array(2) { ["title"]=> string(25) "RLI Class #42 Graduation " ["event_date"]=> string(9) "2012-8-16" }
```

And var_dump for $events outputs

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/newmedia/public_html/dev/wp-gallerific/wp-content/themes/lajcc-theme/calendar.php on line 165
array(0) { } array(2) { ["T"]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(1) "T" ["event_date"]=> string(1) "T" } [2]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(1) "2" ["event_date"]=> string(1) "2" } } array(3) { ["T"]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(1) "T" ["event_date"]=> string(1) "T" } [2]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(1) "2" ["event_date"]=> string(1) "2" } ["R"]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(1) "R" ["event_date"]=> string(1) "R" } }
```

Comment: Why would you want the key (event_date) also input as a value within your array?
Wouldn't it be easier just to have an associative array with the event_date as key and the title as its value?
Or is that not applicable for your application?

Comment: I guess it's not applicable for my application. I need the output exactly as desired. Have been trying a lot of things but just can't nail it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `foreach()` through your array to get the desired output.

Give this a try:

```
$events = array(); ## Declare the new array.
foreach ($array as $line) {
   $event_date = $line['event_date']; ## Set event_date to a variable
   $events[$event_date] = array( 'title' => $line['title'], 'event_date' => $event_date );  ###add new value to new array with key value
}
var_dump($events);  ##display the reults
```

Good luck!

Comment: In order to get the desired result, I'd change the 4th line of your code:
`$events[$event_date] = array( 'title' => $line['title'], 'event_date' => $event_date );`

Comment: I apologize, I missed the data key/value completely! Thanks!

Comment: Nopes. It displays 
`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/newmedia/public_html/dev/wp-gallerific/wp-content/themes/lajcc-theme/calendar.php on line 164
NULL
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/newmedia/public_html/dev/wp-gallerific/wp-content/themes/lajcc-theme/calendar.php on line 164
array(0) { }
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/newmedia/public_html/dev/wp-gallerific/wp-content/themes/lajcc-theme/calendar.php on line 164
array(0) { }`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you executing

```
$events = array(); ## Declare the new array.
```

inside your `while` ? Each iteration basically erase all data set from previous iterations. Just put that line above your `while` (outside, one live above) and `var_dump($events)` after your `endwhile`.

Comment: Tried it outside the loop and still returns `array(0) { }
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/newmedia/public_html/dev/wp-gallerific/wp-content/themes/lajcc-theme/calendar.php on line 164
array(0) { }
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/newmedia/public_html/dev/wp-gallerific/wp-content/themes/lajcc-theme/calendar.php on line 164
array(0) { } `

Comment: Then you are not showing all the relevant code, because there is no way, with what you provided, that you'd get this warning.

Comment: You are right. I had mistakenly omitted the $array line from the last code. However, it still gives some errors. I have updated the code with the outputs.